# Prove that this sequence converges

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to show that $ |r^n|$ converges for $0<|r|<1$.  I know this converges to $0$.  The problem that I have is that I need to use the observation that $\lim_{x\to inf}|r^{n+1}|=\lim_{n\to inf}|r^{n}|$, to show that $|r^n|$ converges to both $rA$ and $A$.  I have already showed that it converges to $A$.

I am sorry if this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but if you need clarification, I will do my best.

Comment: Your title refers to a series, but you seem to be talking about the sequence $\{ r^n\}_{n \geq 1}$. Which is it? Also, you have $x \to \inf$ - I'm not sure what that means. There isn't even an $x$ in the expression. Did you mean $\liminf_{n \geq 1} |r^{n+1}|$? Also, what is $A$?

Comment: sorry, fixed.  A is just what it converges to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to\inf} |r^{n+1}| = r\lim_{n\to\inf} |r^n|$. Can you take it from there?